# MapStruct doesn't update existing target object

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

According to section '3.6. Updating existing bean instances' in https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#updating-bean-instances
MapStruct can update an existing instance of target

However I didn't manage to implement it. Below is my code:

```
public class Source {
    private final String id;
    private final String other;
    Source(String id, String other) {
        this.id = id;
        this.other = other;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getOther() {
        return other;
    }
}


public class Destination {
    private final String id;
    private final String other;

    Destination(String id, String other) {
        this.id = id;
        this.other = other;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getOther() {
        return other;
    }

}


import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.MappingTarget;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

@Mapper
public interface Mapper {
 
    Mapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(Mapper.class );
 
    Destination createDestinationFromSource(Source source);
    updateDestinationFromSource(Source source, @MappingTarget Destination destination);

}

@Test
void testMapStruct() {
        // Create
        var source = new Source("sourceId", "sourceOther");
        var destination1 = Mapper.INSTANCE.createDestinationFromSource(source);
        Assertions.assertEquals(source.getId(), destination1.getId());

        // Update
        var destination2=new Destination("destinationId", "destinationOther");
        Mapper.INSTANCE.updateDestinationFromSource(source, destination2);
        Assertions.assertEquals(source.getId(), destination2.getId()); // Fails
}
```

As can be seen from the code above the creation of target object is successful, but update doesn't work.

Even after I had removed the final-modifiers from the fields of `Destination` and `Source` and added setters to them the update didn't succeed.

Not sure what I'm missing.

Using:

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.2.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.2.Final</version>
            </dependency>
```

and

```
openjdk 17 2021-09-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17+35-2724)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-2724, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: `Destination` has no setters, and its fields are final. How do you expect MapStruct to update instances?

Comment: @RobSpoor How does it create instances then?

Comment: @ka3ak with the constructor

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out, the problem was caused by executing the test from Intellij IDEA which probably didn't recompile/generate the code related to mapping. Executing `mvn clean compile` from the project root directory solved the issue.

However the observations are still the same:
Target object creation works without setters in target object, update works only with setters in target object.